# Swift handle date change event

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, date

How can I handle date change event in swift?

I want to create a set of notification when the date changes.

```
 var localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification.alertBody = " Woww it works!!"
    localNotification.fireDate = date
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`. This one should fire when the day changes.

Unfortunately this one also fires on other occasions. So you should store a static variable with the date the last time this notification fired and then check if it actually changed the *day*.

I don't know what you're gonna use it for, but in most cases the general *significant time change* is what one is looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't look at some stored state, your code should just say "something has happened, I now make sure that all time information is displayed correctly". Independent of when you thought the last call was, and independent on when the last call was (which is probably not the same in many cases).

Comment: Apart from that, this is a very easy way to get a notification usually once a day at midnight, sometimes later, missing some if the phone is not in use for a few days, some additional once when the user changes the clock etc., but this should just trigger code that should be clever enough to do the right thing once it is called.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr will this work if the app is in background? how to use this in swift is this a correct way?

       func applicationSignificantTimeChange(application: UIApplication)
    {
        println("Time Changed")
        
    }

Comment: @HamedAlSuleimani I think the snippet you posted should do its job.

Comment: @gnasher729 You are absolutely right. That's why I said that most of the time a *significant time change* is what you want to observe. I just stated this is how one could achieve the behavior OP described in his question.

Comment: @gnasher729 this code only run if I open the application is there a way that it run without running the application?

Answer (score 1):

You could do `localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)` which will give you a notification 1 day from the current date. This could be further customized to your liking depending on how specific you want the timing to be.

EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, the `timeIntervalSinceNow` is calculated in seconds, so 1 would be one second, not one day.

EDIT 2: Trying to answer the question that was asked. If you want to create a notification at midnight every day...

First, create an `NSCalendar` object

```
var calendar = NSCalendar()
var calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()
calendarComponents.setDay(29)
calendarComponents.setMonth(6)
calendarComponents.setYear(2015)
calendarComponents.setHour(12)
calendarComponents.setSeconds(0)
calendarcomponents.setMinutes(0)
calendar.setTimeZone(NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone)
var dateToFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)
```

Now we can schedule the notification daily.

```
localNotification.fireDate = dateToFire
localNotification.setTimeZone(NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone)
localNotification.setRepeatInterval(kcfCalendarUnitDay)
```

Syntax might not be perfect, I was translating from Obj-C, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: The parameter for `timeIntervalSinceNow` is in seconds, so `1` is not going to advance by 1 day but by 1 second.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, you're right. So in this case you could multiply the number to get the desired length of time.

Comment: @pbush25 if I want to set notification for the whole year this is not an efficient way. I want to handle date change event

Comment: What do you mean you want to handle date change event? Could you be more specific please?

Comment: for example, Today is 29 when this date change to 30 I want to add list of notifications.

Comment: Do you want the notification to happen immediately when the date changes, like midnight?

Comment: @pbush25 no at specific time but every midnight I create this list

Comment: You said not at a specific time but then you said every midnight, so I'm confused as to what you want.

Comment: @pbush25 I will explain it more deeply, every day I get new values these values are the time of the notification, At every day midnight I need to schedule their notifications. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

Try adding observer for `NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged`

The down side of this that it triggers only when app is in foreground